# Até que ponto uma edição é irrelevante?

Tags: suporte, edição

Hoje fiz minha primeira edição, foi uma pergunta onde o enunciado e exemplo estava escrito tudo sem quebras de linha:

> sou iniciante no java, eu queria saber se existe alguma função que facilitasse a minha vida para que: tendo um vetor de n posições preenchido com números(pre-definidos), distribuir esses números nas posições de uma matriz de forma aleatória, por ex: tendo um vetor de 10 posições com 10 números e uma matriz 15x10, distribuir esses 10 números de forma aleatória nas posições da matriz, no caso, a posição que eventualmente não for preenchida não teria problemas. Grato

([Inserir n pontos de um vetor randomicamente em uma matriz axb qualquer em java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325414/inserir-n-pontos-de-um-vetor-randomicamente-em-uma-matriz-axb-qualquer-em-java))

Achei relevante deixar a pergunta mais fácil de ser lida e entendida com formatações simples separando o "olá", a pergunta e o exemplo, desta forma sugeri a seguinte edição:

> Sou iniciante no java, eu queria saber se existe alguma função que facilitasse a minha vida para que:
>
> Tendo um vetor de **n** posições preenchido com números  (pre-definidos), distribuir esses números nas posições de uma matriz de forma aleatória.
>
> Por exemplo: tendo um vetor de 10 posições com 10 números e uma matriz 15x10, distribuir esses 10 números de forma aleatória nas posições da matriz, no caso, a posição que eventualmente não for preenchida não teria problemas.
>
> Grato.

Essa edição não está entre as sugestões principais da central de ajuda para fazer edições:

- corrigir erros de gramática ou ortografia
- esclarecer o significado de uma publicação sem alterá-la
- corrigir pequenos erros ou adicionar/atualizar informações em publicações mais antigas
- adicionar recursos relacionados ou links

Neste caso a edição foi realmente irrelevante? Devo fazer edições a partir de erros de ortografia até perguntas confusas, mas não de formatações "estéticas"?

O objetivo desta pergunta é realmente entender quando devo fazer edições ou não, para assim contribuir da melhor forma com o site.

PS: pensei estar ajudando a leitura da pergunta mas recebi duas rejeições dizendo exatamente que a edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida.

Comment: Flávio, eu acho que dependendo das edições que você faz (deixando de editar algumas outras coisas), isso pode ser visto como uma tentativa de "caçar pontos de reputação". Não que seja ruim alguém caçar reputação, porque é o objetivo do site, mas quando as edições começam a ficar supérfluas demais só para isso, aí é ruim.

Comment: Eu tenho reputação o suficiente para editar a vontade as perguntas e resposta e confesso que gosto do seu tipo de edição. Eu mesmo faço muito.

Comment: @FlavioAndrade, Suponho, porque mesmo com a sua edição a qualidade da pergunta não tem uma nenhuma melhora em seu conteúdo e provavelmente seria marcada para ser fechada como "ampla demais" ou "não está clara o suficiente", com ou sem ela.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendo, realmente é difícil avaliar a boa intenção ou não, eu mesmo tenho este privilégio há muito tempo mas sempre tive a cautela de ter certeza que a edição era necessária ou não. Resolvi fazer essa primeira por julgar ser necessário, mas devido a rejeição só estou tentando entender melhor mesmo quando fazer, até para não ficar com receio de fazer outras.

Comment: Eu já não aprovaria essa edição: como é um parágrafo pequeno, separá-lo em 3 não facilita em nada o entendimento, como propõe o propósito da edição. Se fosse um bloco bem maior de texto tudo junto, seria relevante quebrar em parágrafos. A intenção com certeza é boa. Eu não fico olhando os subterrâneos das pessoas (até que me façam ver o contrário). Só acho que se tivesse um erro muito "grosso" no meio do texto (que prejudicaria o entendimento), aí vc poderia aproveitar para quebrar o texto em parágrafos. Eu aprovaria. Mas só quebrar um "textinho" desse em parágrafos não acho que melhora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu concordo com sua edição. De fato, quebrar a linha em blocos semânticos do texto facilita muito para o leitor. Eu aprovaria a edição, mas aceito quem reprovou pelo fato que não ser apenas isso o que há para editar na pergunta.

Vejamos. Lendo a frase:

> Sou iniciante no java, eu queria saber se existe alguma função que facilitasse a minha vida para que

Foram exatamente 100 caracteres, no início da pergunta, que não adicionaram nada ao contexto. Chamamos isso de ruído e deve ser eliminado.

1. Não faz diferença dizer se é iniciante ou não, a resposta será a mesma. Buscamos sempre respostas canônicas, então para resolver um problema, haverá uma mesma linha de raciocínio, não importando se é iniciante ou avançado na linguagem. Se o autor da pergunta, por ventura, não entender a resposta recebida, cabe a ele comentar pedindo uma explicação ou correr atrás de aprender dadas as novas informações apresentadas na resposta. As vezes, só de existir o termo técnico correto na resposta já permite o autor pesquisar corretamente.
2. Todo o resto da frase poderia ser substituída por "Como faz?", mas se está perguntando, parte-se do princípio que o autor não conseguiu fazer. Redundância, que é outro tipo de ruído.

Sendo assim, os primeiros 100 caracteres da pergunta poderiam ser eliminados sem efeitos colaterais.

Outro ponto é que a pergunta é, literalmente, um "como faz?". Se partiremos do princípio que o autor não conseguiu resolver, temos que saber o que ele, de fato, tentou fazer. Geralmente pedimos ao autor o código que ele tentou e que explique qual foi o resultado obtido. Com isso, saberemos o que o autor não entendeu e, principalmente, onde ele está errando, permitindo, assim, uma resposta mais clara. Mas nem sempre o autor consegue sequer iniciar o código, então nesses casos é interessante pelo menos pedir ao autor que ele descreva, com palavras mesmo, como ele acha que poderia ser resolvido o problema. Fazendo isso, ele basicamente criará o algoritmo que gerará a resposta.

A edição não resolveu os dois pontos principais, então poderia ser rejeitada, com razão. O que eu costumava fazer quando ainda dependia da aprovação de outros usuários era: "a forma com que eu deixei a pergunta fará com que ela seja bem aceita na comunidade?". Se a resposta for sim, pode fazer a edição; mas se ainda for não, e mesmo depois da edição a pergunta correr o risco de ser fechada, do que adianta? Provavelmente depois de fechada ela terá que ser reeditada. Melhor fazer tudo de uma só vez.

Comment: Viu, a edição do ramaral foi perfeitamente válida :D

Comment: E melhorando a resposta quem sabe não precise mais da edição. Ou precisa de outra pra corrigir os novos erros (como já dito na resposta).